# Plotting a blackbody function (Planck curve) using gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, curve, astronomy

I'm trying to use gnuplot to plot a standard blackbody curve (Planck function) and Wien approximation to match a set of given stellar data.

The data plots fine within an (arbitrary) y-range of 0 to 1.4 units. However, no matter what I do, the Planck and Wien curves come out nearly 0 everywhere – all points are in the range of 1e-27.

Am I perhaps defining the functions wrong, or is gnuplot setting very small numbers to zero without me knowing?

Here is the gnuplot code I'm using:

```html
set title "Planck and Wien functions (blackbody curve)" font "Helvetica,14"; \

set out "ps3g0ivplot.eps"

set xrange ["0":"1.1e4"]; \

#set yrange ["0":"1.4"]; \

set ylabel "Arbitrary flux" font "Helvetica,14"; \

set xlabel "Wavelength (Angstrom)" font "Helvetica,14"; \

set mxtics; \

set mytics; \

#constants
h = 6.62606876e-34   # Planck's constant
c = 2.99792458e8   # speed of light
k = 1.3806503e-23   # Boltzmann's constant

Planck(x,t) = \
 (2*h*c*c/x**5)*(exp(-1*h*c/(x*k*t))-1)

Wien(x,t) = \
 (2*h*c**2/x**5)*exp((-1*h*c)/(x*k*t))

#set temperature, t
t = 6400 #in Kelvin, to match given star in ps3g0iv.dat

#print Planck(4500, t)
#print Wien(4500, t)

plot \
 Wien(x,t) lt 2 lw 3 title "Wien" , \
 Planck(x,t) lt 1 lw 3 title "Planck", \
 #"ps3g0iv.dat" lt 9 pt 1 pointsize 1 title "ps3g0iv.dat" with lines

quit
```

Comment: If x is given in Angstrom, then you must replace x by `x*1e-10` to have the correct formula.

Comment: Just a tip, you don't need ; \ in the end of the sets.

Comment: Thank you Christoph, I'll try that out.

And thanks for the stylistic tip Jonatan, those are leftovers from somewhere they were needed a while ago, but I'm taking them out.

Comment: And the Planck function is wrong, should be `(2*h*c**2/x**5)/(exp(h*c/(x*k*t)) - 1)`. The thing with the scaling of x is just a matter of xrange and grange selection.

Comment: Thanks Christoph, that's what happens when you try to finish assignments at 2am I guess. I suspect there's just some scaling needed too. Will try it out in a bit.